# Mutable method parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, parameters, mutable

Simple problem: I am subclassing a FilterInputStream in Scala, which has a read method:

```
public void read(byte [] b,int offset,int len)
```

The data being read will be put in b, but as parameters are "vals" in Scala methods, I see no way to properly subclass this. How do I set b to the data being read? The Java *InputStream really leaves me not much choice....

Answer (score 8):

You can put an item into `b` at index `i` simply by doing `b(i) = whatever`. That `b` is a `val` doesn't have an effect on this. It just means that you can't reassign `b` (which wouldn't be useful to do anyway).

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I considered the array itself immutable - which it need not be. Funny that I never ran into this so far (most of my code is pure Scala, and then you use different patterns - at least I do :-)

Answer (score 6):

Just declaring something as a `val` instead of a `var` in Scala doesn't make it immutable.  In fact, `var` can name an immutable value.  The thing to remember is that variables in Scala, much like variables in Java, are always* [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)), or handles, rather than actually containing the value.

Try this in your REPL:

```
class Container { var content: String = "default" }
val a = new Container
val b = a
b.content = "modified"
println(a.content)
```

When you run `val b = a` you are making `b` and `a` names for the same thing (not a copy, the exact same instance of Container).  Because of this, when you run `b.content = "modified"` the change is reflected in `a` as well; it is just another name for the same thing.  Note this happens even though `a` is a val.  All the `val` means is that you can't change what instance `a` is a name for.

Now think about this slight variation:

```
class Container { var content: String = "default" }
def update(c: Container) { c.content = "modified" }
val a = new Container
update(a)
println(a.content)
```

When you call `update`, its parameter `c` is **also** a reference or alias for `a`.  So changes are reflected outside the method call the same way they are in the earlier example.

Arrays are mutable, so they work like this as well.

*: Primitive variables (bytes, doubles, ints, etc.) are not references in Java; their boxed equivalents (java.lang.Byte...) are.  It doesn't show that much since these classes/types are immutable anyway.

Answer (score 5):

```
def read(b: Array[Byte], offset: Int, len: Int): Unit
```

is equivanet to following in Java:

```
public void read(final byte[] b, final int offset, final int len)
```

The array `b` is still mutable, and you can modify its contents.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder where @missingfaktor find the time to be everywhere :-)

Comment: @olle kullberg I think, it's a team of developers working under one account :)